# Set or update data in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, compiler-errors

Via LINQ
I want to compare the the record's id = the parameter's id
then I want set or update the doc_id in the same record.
I've wrote some lines here:

```
public void Fill_WF_Doc(string ID, int doc)
{
    DataClasses1DataContext DB = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    Waiting_Task entry = new Waiting_Task();
    var c = from D in DB.Waiting_Tasks
            where (D.WF_ID == ID)
            select D.Doc_ID;
    c = doc;
 }
```

but i had this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'

Any help? Thank you.

Comment: Also, you should enclose `DB` with a using statement since it implements `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 1):

By not invoking a call to `GetEnumerator` on your query you are not actually retrieving anything from the database.  Wrap your query in `()` and use `ToList()`, `First()`, `Single()` or others to invoke the query.

```
Waiting_Task entry = (from D in DB.Waiting_Tasks
                      where (D.WF_ID == ID)
                      select D).FirstOrDefault();
```

From there by only returning the Id you are going to return a single `int`, if you want to update your Entity return the full object by using `select D`

> I want set or update the doc_id in the same record.

From there you can simply update the value and `SubmitChanges()` to push the updated value back to the database.

```
public void Fill_WF_Doc(string ID, int doc)
{
  DataClasses1DataContext DB = new DataClasses1DataContext();
  Waiting_Task entry = (from D in DB.Waiting_Tasks
                        where (D.WF_ID == ID)
                        select D).FirstOrDefault();
  entry.Doc_ID = doc;

  DB.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that's because your LINQ expression return an IEnumerable becuse of the Select.

the line that throw the exception is showed below:

```
 public void Fill_WF_Doc(string ID, int doc)
    {
        DataClasses1DataContext DB = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        Waiting_Task entry = new Waiting_Task();
        var c = from D in DB.Waiting_Tasks
                where (D.WF_ID == ID)
                select D.Doc_ID;
        c = doc;//this throw an exception as doc is an Int but c is an ienumerable

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    // c is an IEQueryable<int>
    var c = from D in DB.Waiting_Tasks
            where (D.WF_ID == ID)
            select D.Doc_ID;
    // Error is here, you affect an int to an IQueryable<int>
    c = doc;
```

What are you trying to do?

---

EDIT

To update c.WF_ID you do:

```
var c = (from D in DB.Waiting_Tasks
        where (D.WF_ID == ID)
        select D.Doc_ID).FirstOrDefault();
if(c != null)
{
    c.WF_ID = doc;
}
```

Comment: to insert a value Doc_id column which D.WF_ID == ID

Answer (score 0):

The result of the `select` operation is an `IEnumerable<T>` in your case an `IEnumerable<int>` as Doc_ID is of type int.

I would say you do this:

```
c.ToList().ForEach(e => e = doc);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataClasses1DataContext DB = new DataClasses1DataContext();
var docs = from D in DB.Waiting_Tasks
           where (D.WF_ID == ID)
           select D; // select all the docs met the criteria

foreach(var D in docs)
{
    D.Doc_ID = doc;
}
```

or

just

```
DataClasses1DataContext DB = new DataClasses1DataContext();
var docs = DB.Waiting_Tasks.Where(D => D.WF_ID == ID); // or FirstOrDefault() if ID is key or unique constraint
...
```

Answer (score 0):

c returns a (method to get a) list of items, not a single item. You need to either iterate over the result set, and apply your updates, or use one of the Single/First methods to get one value and update it as others have pointed out.

Also, if you want to update a value in an entity, you need to project the entire object out and then edit the value you want to update. By projecting a single ID, the rest of the object type is lost and EF doesn't know how to align your update with the underlying database row.